# Como dimensionar correctamente una estructura con (#pragma pack)? C++

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, pragma

Estoy tratando de enviar una estructura via socket desde un programa escrito en MQL5 a otro escrito en C++ y no me funciona debido al tamaño de la estructura.

Con la parte de MQL5 no tengo problema. La estuctura tiene el tamaño que se supone debe de tener (14*8=112 bytes).

Sin embargo en C++ la estructura es solo de 80 bytes. Mas pequeña de lo que se supone debería ser.

He estado leyendo en StackOverflow y encontré tres hilos que hablaban sobre (#pragma pack) y sobre (**attribute**((packed))). Sin embargo los he intentado usar y parece no tener ningun efecto. No sé si es que lo estoy haciendo mal o es que simplemente no funciona.

Esta es la estructura: (debería 112 bytes y solo tiene 80 bytes)

```
#pragma pack (8)
struct Deal
{
   long     deal_ticket;         // deal ticket
   long     order_ticket;        // the ticket of the order by which the deal was executed
   long     position_ticket;     // ID of the position to which the deal belongs
   long     time;                // deal execution time
   long     type;                // deal type
   long     entry;               // deal direction   
   char     symbol[8];           // the symbol fro which the deal was executed
   double   volume;              // operation volume
   double   price;               // price
   double   profit;              // financial result
   double   swap;                // swap
   double   commission;          // commission
   long     magic;               // Magic number (Expert Advisor ID)
   long     reason;              // deal execution reason or source
};//__attribute__((packed));


int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(Deal) << endl;
}
```

Estoy usando este compilador --> TDM-GCC-64

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda!!

Comment: Para solucionar este tipo de eventualidades lo que se suele hacer es serializar la información. Enviar bytes en bruto es muy delicado porque cualquier cambio en la arquitectura del hardware hace que la comunicación deje de funcionar

Comment: En cualquier caso, si la serialización no es viable, deberías empezar por ver cuánto ocupa cada tipo de dato en MQL5 y buscar tipos que ocupen exactamente lo mismo en C++ (piensa que en C++ los tipos no ocupan lo mismo en 32 bits que en 64 bits). Eligiendo los tipos adecuados ambas estructuras deberían ocupar lo mismo

Comment: Si no, también puedes almacenar la respuesta en un buffer y después procesar ese buffer para ir rellenando a mano la estructura de C++

Comment: OK, Si he mirado los tipos de datos. Todos los que estoy usando tienen un tamaño de 8 bytes... como se hace eso de serializar?... También pensé en usar un buffer pero queria dejarlo como ultima alternativa porque pensé que sería mas eficiente usar una estructura... Muchas gracias por tu respuesta *eferion*

Comment: He sustituido todos los "long" por "std::int64_t" y aparantemente se ha solucionado el problema... ahora me he quedado con la intriga de que es eso de serializar XD...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda *eferion*

Comment: Serializar consiste en coger una estructura y almacenar sus datos de tal forma que luego puedan ser recuperados en cualquier otro momento. Existen numerosos protocolos para serializar información: XDR, ASN.1, Json, protocol buffers, XML, ...

Comment: Por otro lado piensa que lo más lento de una comunicación por sockets es justamente el envío de datos. El tiempo que se tarda en serializar pequeños objetos es ridículo (ns) en comparación con el tiempo que se tarda en enviar dichos datos (ms)

Comment: Ok, ya comprendo que es. Muchisímas gracias por la explicación!!

Comment: Si lo del socket no es lo suficientemente rápido probaré lo de la serialización. Precisamente estoy usando el socket porque guardar los datos en una base de datos de SQLite era demasiado lento... estoy tratando de guardar unos datos antes de que se borren de la memoria. Se generan en unos hilos que no puedo controlar durante una optimización de un algoritmo génetico y solo tengo acceso a ellos durante pequeño instante antes de que se borren para ser usados en la siguiente generación... asi que si, necesito que sea lo mas rápido posible... Gracias por la idea!!